# Criteria inside JsonPath

Tags: java, jsonpath

I'm trying to filter jsonPath by type. To extract Integers

I would expect this will return nothing as 'xx' is not integer:

```
JsonPath.read("{'status': 'xx'}", "$.status", Criteria.where(".status").is(Integer.class));
```

Similarly this

```
JsonPath.read("{'status': 'xx'}", "$.status", Criteria.where(".status").eq(200));
```

both cases returns String = "xx"
I would expect it to return either null or empty string as it doesn't match number 200.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Correct @i.bondarenko, I would simply add - for the first check of searching whether status value is an Integer - that he/she should use a Pattern to pass to the filter, like for example

```
Pattern numberPattern = Pattern.compile("\\d+");
Filter filter = filter(where("status").regex(numberPattern));
Object test = JsonPath.read("{\"status\": \"xx\"}", "$[?].status", filter);

System.out.println("Test : " + test);
```

That will print `Test : []`

**UPDATED**

It is a JSONArray indeed, therefore, you already have the Integers of your whole JSON in that array (if they exist). For example,

```
Pattern numberPattern = Pattern.compile("\\d+");
Filter filter = filter(where("status").regex(numberPattern));
net.minidev.json.JSONArray test = JsonPath.read("{\"status\": 300}", "$[?].status", filter);

if (!test.isEmpty()) {
    for (Object object : test) {
         System.out.println("Test : " + object.toString());
    }
}
```

So, there is no need to add `try-catch`, it is enough to just check the size of your JSONArray result

Comment: thanks. Seem to work but as the output is JsonArray and stuff, I'd better do try { } catch (MappginException) in that case to determine if it is Integer.

Answer (score 2):

You should use `$[?].status` as json path for criteria.
Also `where("field").is("value")` accept value but not a class.
You could have a look at implementation of Criteria.eq(...)

```
public Criteria eq(Object o) {
    return is(o);
}
```

Here is the code:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Criteria criteria = Criteria.where("status").gt(10);
    Object read = JsonPath.read("{'status': 18}", "$[?].status", criteria);
    System.out.println("First: " + read);
    read = JsonPath.read("{'status': 2}", "$[?].status", criteria);
    System.out.println("Second: " + read);

    criteria = Criteria.where("status").is("value");
    read = JsonPath.read("{'status': 'value'}", "$[?].status", criteria);
    System.out.println("Third: " + read);

    criteria = Criteria.where("status").is("value");
    read = JsonPath.read("{'status': 'NON'}", "$[?].status", criteria);
    System.out.println("Third: " + read);
}
```

***Output:***

```
First: [18]
Second: []
Third: ["value"]
Third: []
```